# Kernel crash when evaluating NDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, crash, finite-element-method, difference-equations

I had a code that was working fine and I tried to add an extra few lines to find the solution of the same equation with different conditions. The original NDSolveValue solutions work fine but when it gets to evaluating solnG it just makes a "Ding" and stops evaluating the code. What is the cause of this sound and why will it not continue to evaluate the code?

Here is the code:

```
<< "NDSolve`FEM`"

ts = .000250; tsl = .000250; (* m *)
ρs = 3980;  ρsl = 958; (* kg/m3 *)
ks = .035;  ksl = .00067; (* kW/m/K *)
cs = .75; csl = 4.22; (* kJ/kg/K *)

ρ = If[0 <= z < ts, ρs, ρsl];
k = If[0 <= z < ts, ks, ksl];
c =  If[0 <= z < ts, cs, csl];

td = 0.075;
tg = 0.01;

eqn1 = k*D[T1[z], z] + 28; 
Tbl = 100;
Subscript[Γ1, D] = DirichletCondition[T1[z] == Tbl, z == ts + tsl];

BCr = NDSolveValue[{eqn1 == 0, Subscript[Γ1, D]}, T1, {z, 0, ts + tsl}];

Plot[BCr[z], {z, 0, ts + tsl}, GridLines -> {{ts}, {0}}]

Ti[z_] := \[Piecewise] {
    {BCr[z], 0 <= z < ts},
    {100, True}
   };
Plot[Ti[z], {z, 0, ts + tsl}, GridLines -> {{ts}, {0}}]

eqn2 = c ρ Derivative[1, 0][T][t, z] - k Derivative[0, 2][T][t, z]
Subscript[Γ, D] = DirichletCondition[T[t, z] == Tbl, z == ts + tsl];
Subscript[Γ, N] = NeumannValue[-28, z == 0];

solnD = 
  NDSolveValue[
    {eqn2 == Subscript[Γ, N], 
     Subscript[Γ, D], T[0, z] == Ti[z]}, 
    T, {t, 0, 1}, {z, 0, ts + tsl}, 
    Method -> 
      {"PDEDiscretization" -> 
        {"MethodOfLines", 
         "SpatialDiscretization" -> 
           {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> (ts + tsl)/1011}}}}]

Plot[solnD[t, ts], {t, 0, 1}, GridLines -> {{0}, {107}}, PlotRange -> Full]
Plot[solnD[td, z], {z, 0, ts + tsl}, GridLines -> {{ts}, {0}}]

eqn3 = ρ c D[Tg[t, z], t] - k D[Tg[t, z], z, z]; 
TiG[z_] := solnD[td, z];
Plot[TiG[z], {z, 0, ts}]
Tits = solnD[td, ts];
Subscript[Γd, N] = NeumannValue[-28, z == 0];

solnG = 
  NDSolveValue[
    {eqn3 == Subscript[Γd, N], 
     (Tg[t, z] /. z -> ts) == (-300*t + Tits), 
     Tg[0, z] == TiG[z]},
    Tg, {t, 0, .1}, {z, 0, ts}, 
    Method -> 
      {"PDEDiscretization" -> 
        {"MethodOfLines", 
         "SpatialDiscretization" -> 
           {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> (ts)/1011}}}}]

Animate[
  Plot[solnG[t, z], {z, 0, ts}, PlotRange -> {99, 111}], {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. Which lines did you change?

Comment: Do you mean the kernel crashed? (The "ding.")

Comment: @MichaelE2, yes, I get a kernel crash.

Comment: I did not change any of the original lines. I only added to the end of the code and initialized the variables 'td' and 'tg' at the top. It is strange because I had to comment out the animation line because I was getting errors from that animation and it was all working before. This would imply there is something wrong above the new code but other than the new code at the bottom and the initialization of the variables nothing changed.

Comment: I just realized I also changed 'soln' to 'solnD' for clarification. I changed it to 'solnd' and now the kernel does not crash. Apparently the capitalization makes a difference. There new NDSolveValue solution 'solng' is still not working but the animation is.

Comment: I didn't change the name of 'solnD' to 'solnd' everywhere in the code but now that I have I am getting the same kernel crash and the animation does not work. Capitalization does not matter. The crash is from trying to solve for 'solnG'. I have determined that the crash seems to come from using the solution from 'solnD'  as the initial condition for 'solnG'. When use a different initial condition the crash does not occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug. As a workaround try using:

```
TiG[z_?NumericQ] := solnD[td, z];
```